# Checking the history of a file

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp

I'm trying to setup a shortcut, a command which will let me check the history of one file.

I'm interested in when the file was originally commited, in what changesets it was changed and whether the current version in the working directory differs from the "last commited one".

So, in general

```
 hg log --verbose filename.txt
 hg status filename.txt
```

Is there a way to make this into a sort of a shortcut, so I can just type for example

```
hg file filename.txt
```

and get the "history" of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a [shell alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias):

```
[alias]
file = !$HG log --verbose "$1" && $HG status "$1"
```

The `$HG` environment variable refers to the path of the `hg` script used to invoke the shell alias, just in case `hg` is not in your path. The `$1` refers to the first command line argument, the file name in your case.

Comment: I'm using it in this form: file = !hg log --verbose $1; hg status $1
 .... However, this just displays the result of hg log --verbose, the hg status does not follow?!

Comment: Try with `&&` instead of `;` to separate the commands — does that work better?